# connectycube server-side read api

Tags: connectycube

As the developer of my app, I want to be able to read and process all the dialogs / messages that my members have written. Including the private dialogs.

I couldn't find any way in the API documentation that makes all the dialogs available. Since all dialog history is accessible via the Connectycube admin panel, it should also be available in the API.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no such an API, as only a user can get own chat dialogs.

There is only one way to do so  - via Admin panel, where all chat dialogs available for an application